# How to get the environment variable from .env file on to a docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

I have an `.env` file and a docker-compose file. I reference the env file using the `env_file` property on the docker-compose. Then I use the variable interpolation to set another environment variable using the variable defined in the .env file. For some reason, Docker doesn't recognize the variable defined in the .env file.

**app.env**:

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
DB_USER=root
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  wordpress:
    container_name: 'wp'
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - mysql
    env_file:
      - app.env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you mixed up the meaning of the [env_file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option) configuration option. It is passing multiple environment variables from an external file through to a service’s containers. It is the same as `environment`, but they are loaded from the file.

If you want to `docker compose` recognize the variable defined in the `.env` file it should be exactly [.env](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) file.

To achieve what you want you need:

**1.** Rename `app.env` to `.env`:

```
mv app.env .env
```

**2.** Delete `env_file` configuration option from `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  wordpress:
    container_name: 'wp'
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Comment: No luck, the environment vars aren't set at all

Comment: Do you need environment variables for image building or to inject them into container?

Comment: Inject them into the container

Comment: My answer is exactly about that. It works fine on my linux host,

Comment: I'm on a Windows machine, and the variable interpolation doesn't seem to work for Environment variables. Is there any docs online that specifies this variable interpolation on the environment block?

Comment: I checked your solution on a Mac, and it worked as you mentioned. Unfortunately, the windows is still an issue.

Comment: NVM, I think I must have entered things wrong earlier. It's working like a charm now on Windows. Thanks

Comment: how add comments in the .env?